# UIView - What override will allow updating a UIView frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIView .xib, and am subclassing UIView. When I load the Nib, the frame of the view is set and awakeFromNib() is called.

I have 3 buttons. When I load the view, I pass in callbacks for each button. If one or more of the callbacks is nil, then I hide the buttons and resize the view:

```
let viewSize = 50
var adjustedSize = 0
if (self.option2String == nil){
    self.option2View.isHidden = true
    adjustedSize -= viewSize
}
if (self.option3String == nil){
    self.option3View.isHidden = true
    adjustedSize -= viewSize
}
let _size = self.innerView.frame.size
let size = CGSize(width: _size.width, height: _size.height + CGFloat(adjustedSize))
self.innerView.frame = CGRect(origin: self.innerView.frame.origin, size: size)
```

I have tried putting this code in awakeFromNib(), and didMoveToSuperview(), but the frame does not change size.

If I enclose the last line in DispatchQueue.main.async, then it works. But I'm concerned that this is just luck due to timing.

Is this best practice? Where can I resize a view from within a UIView subclass?

EDIT: Confirmed, the DispatchQueue.main.async is just luck. It only works 50% of the time.

Comment: Did you try calling layoutIfNeeded() on super view after setting the frame?

Comment: @ShreeramBhat yes, just tried now and that didn't work

Comment: @ShreeramBhat tried that in awakeFromNib() and didLayoutSubview() and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Having the view inside a UIViewController, call a function that resizes your view inside the controller's viewDidLayoutSubviews()

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   myView.resize()
}
```

Comment: I have a custom Alert view, so I can't just add this code everywhere, it would break everything. What I mean is, I'm using this code in 45 different places. I need to avoid adding special conditional code everywhere to resize a view, especially when the view/views will only exist very conditionally.

Comment: If you subclassed AlertViewController there is also viewDidLayoutSubviews to be overriden.

Comment: im not subclassing AlertViewController, I just created a custom UIView XIB